# Using client side people picker with javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, clientpeoplepicker

I found this [this documentation on how to use the client side people picker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593(v=office.15).aspx) and have it working on my page. Basically you load a bunch of js files, setup a schema, and then initialize the picker.

I'm trying to find any documentation of how you set up the schema and what kind of values you can use.

```
// Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
var schema = {};
schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
schema['Width'] = '280px';

// Render and initialize the picker. 
// Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
// PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
// picker properties.
this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
```

For example I figured out that `PrincipalAccountType` values of User means users, SecGroup is some kind of security group, and SPGroup is SharePoint groups. I couldn't figure out what **DL** is for. What exactly do those mean and are those the only choices?

I also can't figure out what properties I can use in the schema. Are those the only ones?

[This documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.clientpeoplepicker_properties.aspx) seems to list the properties for the people picker, but they don't quite match up. For example, in the code sample I found there is a `schema['AllowMultipleValues']` but in the property list there is `AllowMultipleEntries`.

From the list of properties I've tried some like `Tooltip` which didn't work, but `Title` did set the tooltip.

Does anyone have a good source of information on how to actually work with and configure a client side people picker when using javascript on the page?

**Edit** Bonus question

In the init function what is the second argument? Must it always be `null`?

```
SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(pickerElementId,null,schema)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### What are the `PrincipalAccountType` values

- User = single user
- DL = AD distribution list
- SecGroup = AD security group
- SPGroup = SharePoint group

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor.accounttype.aspx)

### All Properties

You can check the constructor for all possible properties (and some more stuff but you should be able to distinguish them).

The consturctor is located in `/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js`:

```
function SPClientPeoplePicker(controlProps) {
    this.TopLevelElementId = controlProps.TopLevelElementId;
    this.EditorElementId = controlProps.EditorElementId;
    this.AutoFillElementId = controlProps.AutoFillElementId;
    this.ResolvedListElementId = controlProps.ResolvedListElementId;
    this.InitialHelpTextElementId = controlProps.InitialHelpTextElementId;
    this.WaitImageId = controlProps.WaitImageId;
    this.HiddenInputId = controlProps.HiddenInputId;
    if (typeof controlProps.Required != "undefined")
        this.AllowEmpty = !Boolean(controlProps.Required);
    if (typeof controlProps.ForceClaims != "undefined")
        this.ForceClaims = Boolean(controlProps.ForceClaims);
    if (typeof controlProps.AutoFillEnabled != "undefined")
        this.AutoFillEnabled = Boolean(controlProps.AutoFillEnabled);
    if (typeof controlProps.AllowMultipleValues != "undefined")
        this.AllowMultipleUsers = Boolean(controlProps.AllowMultipleValues);
    if (typeof controlProps.AllowEmailAddresses != "undefined")
        this.AllowEmailAddresses = Boolean(controlProps.AllowEmailAddresses);
    if (typeof controlProps.AllUrlZones != "undefined")
        this.AllUrlZones = Boolean(controlProps.AllUrlZones);
    if (typeof controlProps.VisibleSuggestions != "undefined")
        this.VisibleSuggestions = Number(controlProps.VisibleSuggestions);
    if (typeof controlProps.UseLocalSuggestionCache != "undefined")
        this.UseLocalSuggestionCache = Boolean(controlProps.UseLocalSuggestionCache);
    if (typeof controlProps.InitialSuggestions != "undefined" && controlProps.InitialSuggestions != null ) {
        this.InitialSuggestions = controlProps.InitialSuggestions;
        SPClientPeoplePicker.AugmentEntitySuggestions(this, this.InitialSuggestions, false)
    }
    if (typeof controlProps.UrlZone != "undefined")
        this.UrlZone = controlProps.UrlZone;
    if (typeof controlProps.WebApplicationID != "undefined")
        this.WebApplicationID = controlProps.WebApplicationID;
    if (typeof controlProps.SharePointGroupID != "undefined")
        this.SharePointGroupID = Number(controlProps.SharePointGroupID);
    if (typeof controlProps.PrincipalAccountType != "undefined")
        this.PrincipalAccountType = controlProps.PrincipalAccountType;
    if (typeof controlProps.EnabledClaimProviders != "undefined")
        this.EnabledClaimProviders = controlProps.EnabledClaimProviders;
    if (typeof controlProps.ResolvePrincipalSource != "undefined")
        this.ResolvePrincipalSource = controlProps.ResolvePrincipalSource;
    if (typeof controlProps.SearchPrincipalSource != "undefined")
        this.SearchPrincipalSource = controlProps.SearchPrincipalSource;
    if (typeof controlProps.MaximumEntitySuggestions != "undefined")
        this.MaximumEntitySuggestions = Number(controlProps.MaximumEntitySuggestions);
    this.PrincipalAccountTypeEnum = SPClientPeoplePicker.CreateSPPrincipalType(this.PrincipalAccountType);
    var fnUserCallback = controlProps.OnValueChangedClientScript;
    this.OnValueChangedClientScript = fnUserCallback != null ? eval(fnUserCallback) : null ;
    var fnResolvedCallback = controlProps.OnUserResolvedClientScript;
    this.OnUserResolvedClientScript = fnResolvedCallback != null ? eval(fnResolvedCallback) : null ;
    var fnControlValidateCallback = controlProps.OnControlValidateClientScript;
    this.OnControlValidateClientScript = fnControlValidateCallback != null ? eval(fnControlValidateCallback) : null ;
    this.AutoFillControl = null ;
    this.TotalUserCount = 0;
    this.UnresolvedUserCount = 0;
    this.UserQueryDict = {};
    this.ProcessedUserList = {};
    this.UnresolvedUserElmIdToReplace = "";
    if (typeof ClientCanHandleImn == "undefined" || !ClientCanHandleImn())
        SPClientPeoplePicker.ShowUserPresence = false;
    var topLevelElement = document.getElementById(this.TopLevelElementId);
    if (topLevelElement != null ) {
        topLevelElement.setAttribute("SPClientPeoplePicker", "true");
        if (Boolean(controlProps.Width))
            topLevelElement.style.width = controlProps.Width;
        if (controlProps.Width == "100%")
            topLevelElement.className += " ms-fullWidth";
        if (Boolean(controlProps.Rows) && Number(controlProps.Rows) != 0)
            topLevelElement.style.minHeight = String(Number(controlProps.Rows) * 16) + "px"
    }
    var editorElement = document.getElementById(this.EditorElementId);
    editorElement != null && editorElement.setAttribute("data-sp-peoplePickerEditor", "true");
    if (this.ShouldUsePPMRU())
        this.PPMRU = SPClientPeoplePickerMRU.GetSPClientPeoplePickerMRU();
    SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[this.TopLevelElementId] = this
}
```

### Bonus question

The second parameter is an array of users to prefill the peoplepicker. Here's a code example:

```
    var users = new Array(1);
    var defaultUser = new Object();
    defaultUser.AutoFillDisplayText = user.get_title();
    defaultUser.AutoFillKey = user.get_loginName();
    defaultUser.Description = user.get_email();
    defaultUser.DisplayText = user.get_title();
    defaultUser.EntityType = "User";
    defaultUser.IsResolved = true;
    defaultUser.Key = user.get_loginName();
    defaultUser.Resolved = true;
    users[0] = defaultUser;
    SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper('peoplePickerDiv', users, schema);
```

From http://blog.ianchivers.com/2013/05/client-side-people-picker-control-for.html

Comment: Thanks. Clever idea to go into the code and read it. Seems like MS should document it somewhere, though, donit?

Comment: What to do if I have to populate the custom people picker through code? Not at the initial load but later?

Comment: @JefinMathew https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/197281/10271

Comment: SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.CustomPeoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.AddUserKeys('UserEmail');