# How to autofill people picker column with logged in user name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I am using new form in sharepoint designer , so how will i autopopulate name picker field(Name of the submitter) to take logged in user name automatically when form is opened?

Comment: I answered something similar here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/197281/10271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getUser() {
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;


    var requestUri = "https://brillioonline.sharepoint.com/sites/ConnectDeveloperSite/AxisBilling/axisdev" + "/_api/web/getuserbyid(" + userid + ")";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    }); function onSuccess(data, request) {
        var loginName = data.d.Title;

       $("#UserID").append("UserID")
      // $("#UserID").val(loginName )

    } function onError(error) {
        alert("Error on retrieving current user.");
    }
}
getUser();
```

And then we need to append with field value

Answer (score 2):

For NewForm.aspx one of the best way is to use "spservices.js":

don't forget to add reference of spservice.js after jquey:
https://spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/119578

script for Auto popultation is as under:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentUser = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        webURL: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl,
    });
    setCurrentUser(currentUser);
});

function setCurrentUser(accountName) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var userName = accountName;
        var form = jQuery("table[class='ms-formtable']"); 
        var userField = form.find("input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']").get(1) 
        var peoplepicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(userField)
        peoplepicker.AddUserKeys(userName);
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: Hi Rushil do i need to change anything in the code ? My field name is Name of the submitter(Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_su) , i applied your code above but its not working!! Also i used those ref js too! I Am using SP2013 @Rushil Shah

Comment: Make change in the code by replacing below line with corrected one
var userField = form.find("input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']").get(1)
to
var userField = form.find("input[id$='ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput']").get(0)

Comment: Do i need to change these - 'ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput' , userField with my column name? I mentioned the column name can you please tell me how to write there? I am new too javascript

Comment: function setCurrentUser(accountName) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var userName = accountName;
        var form = jQuery("table[class='ms-formtable']"); 
        var userField = form.find("input[id$='Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_su']").get‌​(0) 
        var peoplepicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.PickerObjectFromSubElement(Nameofthesubmitter)
        peoplepicker.AddUserKeys(userName);
    }, 300);
}

Comment: @RushilShah, please [edit] your answer instead add comments with code. Comments are temporary. Thank you. PS: if you have indeed edit your question with the code, please delete your own coments.

Answer (score 2):

No need for jQuery or SPServices (they were handy in SP2007/SP2010 days)

3 lines JavaScript:

```
var inp = document.querySelector("input[title='Assigned To']");
inp.value = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[inp.parentNode.id].AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
```

### Suggestion from comments: 1 line of code:

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[document.querySelector("input[title='Assigned To']").parentNode.id].BatchAddUserKeysOperation([_spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName], 0);
```

see: [Trigger SPClientPeoplePicker to search for string](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197270/trigger-spclientpeoplepicker-to-search-for-string)

Comment: Hey Danny , any extra modification i need to do in this code? My field name is Name of the submitter(Name_x0020_of_x0020_the_x0020_su) and also should i ref some js ? I Am new to javascript please help me out

Comment: Check the HTML source with F12 tools for the correct ``title=`` notation, and execute the code after the form is loaded.. the setTimeOut in the other example is a crude way, but works. Best is to use the Cisar Chrome Extension WYSIWIG Javascript editor (use Google!) and add the code to the OnPostRender function

Comment: Be warned .. That ``OnPostRender`` functions executes once **for every Form Field** So you need to add a check to only execute once

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Just a minimal improvement - no need for setting the input value `picker.BatchAddUserKeysOperation(['userDisplayNameOrLoginOrSearchString'], 0);` also does the trick. 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197270/trigger-spclientpeoplepicker-to-search-for-string/197281#197281

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about SP Designer, but using Infopath you can create a rule on form load to set a field to the current user.

Comment: Can you describe the process for infopath please? @JJD

Comment: 1 Look for the Form load button (it's in the DATA tab in the ribbon.)
2 Make a new rule of type Action, add an action 'Set a fields value'. 
3 In the popup menu pick the field. Click the fx button on the Value field, insert a function of category:User, then select UserName and click ok

Comment: I tried the exact process but its not working bro!!

Answer (score 0):

have you try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('div.ms-inputuserfield').text($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({fieldName: "Title",debug: false}));
</script>
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/342ac0a6-0782-40f8-8c6e-d8b57e494b8b/sharepoint-person-field-auto-fill-with-current-user?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious